# jQuery div rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a hard time trying to find a rotator to fit my needs since I cant seem to make one...

I want to automatically fade rotate a entire div, any help with this?

Comment: Do you mean rotate, as in spin around the center of the div (i.e. rotate 90 degrees or 45 degrees), or do you mean cycling through different content in the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery cycle plugin may work: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It has a lite version too if you only need it to rotate/cycle.

Comment: thanks, this script had what i was looking for, lots more options here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23

Answer (score 0):

Try [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/)... you can rotate image and divs

Answer (score 0):

Im using [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) and rocks...

You could watch a demo [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)